# r bookdown - dynamic custom link text reference chapter and table in link

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to have a link in the text, when reading, that takes you to a chapter or table reference in the book.

The `bookdown` documentation does a great job explaining out to implement link text, and even how to add custom link text in the [cross-reference](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html) section, but I'm trying to add a custom link that is also dynamic with the chapter or table numbers.

For example, I want a custom link to says: *chapter 2*. When I try something like `[Chapter \@ref(chapter_ref)](#chapter_ref)` it kind of works, but there is two separate links that go to the same place which causes alternative text issues.

Any suggestions?